# Stop service workers form resubmitting forms when back button is used

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, back, service-worker, html5-history

When using a service worker to handle a request chrome actually resubmits submitted forms when I hit the back button after I have navigated away from the page by clicking a link.

Without a service worker the default behavior in chrome is to show a cached version of the response I got when I submitted the form.

With a simple service worker that just handles the request by using fetch() chrome actually replays the request when I hit the back button instead.

Is there any simple way to make service workers behave the way chrome does by default?

Tried the same thing over a year ago and then I concluded that it might be a bug, but since it's still like that I guess it's supposed to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into similar problems with back/forward navigation in Firefox. The best thing I've found to do is to sniff the request.cache param for 'only-if-cached' or 'force-cache' and to avoid trying to fetch in the first place.

There's [some more documentation here about request.cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) but it doesn't really document use for an incoming request to a service worker fetch handler properly.